# Why does this simple algebraic expression not simplify to zero?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

Define a simple symbolic expression *a*, then let *b* be the square root of its square:

```
a = A + Sqrt[A + B];

a^2 // Expand

A + A^2 + B + 2 A Sqrt[A + B]


b = Sqrt[%]

Sqrt[A + A^2 + B + 2 A Sqrt[A + B]]
```

The difference, when simplified under the assumption that both *A* and *B* are positive reals should give zero:

```
a - b

A + Sqrt[A + B] - Sqrt[A + A^2 + B + 2 A Sqrt[A + B]]


FullSimplify[%, A > 0 && B > 0 && A ∈ Reals && B ∈ Reals]

A + Sqrt[A + B] - Sqrt[A + A^2 + B + 2 A Sqrt[A + B]]
```

Yet in the symbolic form it doesn't. What am I missing?

Comment: `FullSimplify[a == b, 
 A > 0 && B > 0 && A \[Element] Reals && B \[Element] Reals]` returns `True`, so it is probably just a little too hard for Mathematica

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can "cheat" as follows:

```
FullSimplify[
    A+Sqrt[A+B]-Sqrt[A+A^2+B+2 A Sqrt[A+B]] /. B->c-A,
    0<A<c
]
```

> 0

Here is another variation of this idea:

```
FullSimplify[
    A+Sqrt[A+B]-Sqrt[A+A^2+B+2 A Sqrt[A+B]],
    A+B==c && A>0 && B>0 && c>0
]
```

> 0